# want to configure my apolloclient in my project

Tags: next.js, websocket, graphql, apollo-client

I'm tryig to configure my Apollo client in my graphql project. i configured it earlier and it was working. but I want real-time connectivity between two user, so am trying to add WebSocket to it, but am getting an error: Error: Unable to find native implementation, or alternative implementation for WebSocket!

here was my previous code that was working

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'https://myurl',
    headers: { 'Authorization': `apikey mykey` },
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

export default client;

but here is the code that is not working

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { WebSocketLink } from '@apollo/client/link/ws';
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities';
import { split } from 'apollo-link';
import { SubscriptionClient } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: 'https://myuri',
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: 'wss://myendpoint',
    options:{
        reconnect: true
    }
});

const link = split(
    ({ query }) => {
        const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
        return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && definition.operation === 'subscription';
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```